# Microsoft Live SDK OneDrive ios multiaccounting

Tags: ios, onedrive, live-sdk

If you have experience working with Microsoft OneDrive (ex SkyDrive) using **[their official live-sdk](http://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-iOS)** - have you faced a problem of multi-accounting?

Just on MS forum I found this post (And so I do want to make the same task):

"I'm working on an IOS app using one drive sdk and i need to do a multi connection so user can add more than one account , and then when he click on the account icon i account will be opened , so my idea to do this was to save the accessToken ,authenticationToken,refreshToken,scopes,expires of each account then i will create the LiveConnectSession object using the method :

```
initWithAccessToken:(NSString *)accessToken
authenticationToken:(NSString *)authenticationToken
       refreshToken:(NSString *)refreshToken
             scopes:(NSArray *)scopes
            expires:(NSDate *)expires;
```

then i will set it to the LiveConnectClient , but the broblem is that the session proprety of LiveConnectClient  is read only so i cant change it "

So the MS support tells, that **[right now it is impossible, but still there are apps, that provide multiaccounting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/live/en-US/9ff38dbe-45c6-49db-a037-c5548c56fc6b/how-i-can-set-an-existing-liveconnectsession-to-the-liveconnectclient)**

So now I'm confused.

I will be happy to hear any response.

Comment: This question is not specific to the iPhone.

Comment: @rmaddy, please, you can easily find on SO some questions, that are anyhow connected with iphone. You may edit that tags. (just type skydrive [iphone] in search)

Comment: Just because other posts misuse a tag doesn't mean you should. Read the description of the `iphone` tag. It's meant for questions that are specific to that hardware. Your question is not specific to an iPhone. It's a general iOS question.

Comment: @rmaddy, okay, now I got it. I think, you should comment why you're doing smth, to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: @BraveS did u find any solution

Comment: @MuhammadUmar, unfortunately no, I just work with 1 account at a time.

Comment: @BraveS Why don't u Just set the readonly property to strong. That should do the trick :) I just did it and using refresh token to open account. But i am facing difficulty in how to list all the files in skydrive. Can you give me hints?